# How to allow swagger ui in Spring Custom Filter along with validation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have written the following code where I have created a Custom Filter in SpringBoot which is always passed as Request Header. Request header name licenseKey and some value. I have implemented and also allowed Swagger-UI to work. Please suggest me to follow better approach, my seniors say that it is not a good approach. I provide below the code. The task is to receive licenseKey while calling Rest end point and also we need to allow Swagger-UI without licenseKey that will be provided later as part of authorization in Swagger. Currently the code is working fine. I request for better approach. I provide below the code. I removed all import statements.

```
@Component
public class CustomURLFilter implements Filter {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomURLFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        LOGGER.info("########## Initiating CustomURLFilter filter ##########");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        
        String path = request.getRequestURI();

        System.out.println("Path: "+path);
        if(path.startsWith("/app-name-service/swagger-ui") || path.startsWith("/app-name-service/v3/api-docs")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        } else {
             String licenseKey = userDetailsService.getLicenseKey(request);
             System.out.println("User License Key: "+licenseKey);
        }
        
        LOGGER.info("This Filter is only called when request is mapped for /customer resource");

        //call next filter in the filter chain
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```